# Combining main project with google maps project

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

Quick question regarding Google Maps. I have one fully working Google Maps project and another working project for my main application. I am wondering about combining these. How does one go about doing adding the Google Maps API functionality to the existing Android project.

I have tried researching this online but my search terms seemed to be a bit ambiguous.

Thanks.

Comment: What I was missing was changing the target platform.
Right click on the project > android > tick google maps api instead of the android api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Assuming you are using a Single MapActivity, copy that activity to the other project and change the Target Platform for the existing android project to Google API  <VersionNo>
2. Add the Maps API library to your project's Manifest file

   ```
   <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
   ```
3. Obtain the Maps API key, add to your project and also sign the app with the certificate corresponding to the same key
   http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html

Comment: Thanks, changing number 1 fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily integrate Google maps with a [Maps view](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) into your application.

But make sure you to sign your application with the key that was used for receiving the google maps api key. Otherwise nobody will see the maps when your application is published.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the plugin

Go to:

project,
properties,
android,
on the right hand menu choose the google api of your choice

the library will be added to your project.

Remember you must add the appropriate xml resource from your project and the permissions to your manifest etc